# Numeric TextEdit control +/- sign

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress, mask, textedit

I'm using `Devexpress TextEdit control` in my dialog form, and what I want to achieve, is to give the + sign to the typed value if it's greater than 0. The current EditMask value is set to n2.

> For example :
>
> If the user type 5.00, the control must show **+5.00**.

The user is also allowed to type a negative values. Is there some mask I should use, or a regular expression pattern ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try [Devexpress Support Center](http://www.devexpress.com/Support).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the the ';' character to separate the masks for positive and negative values:

```
textEdit1.Properties.Mask.EditMask = "+#0.00;-#0.00";
textEdit1.Properties.Mask.MaskType = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Mask.MaskType.Numeric;
textEdit1.Properties.Mask.UseMaskAsDisplayFormat = true;
```

Related link: [Mask Type: Numeric](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1498/Custom)

Comment: Thanks for your response, it works fine, except for the 0.00 value, it shows +0.00, is there a way so that it show 0.00 without a sign. thanks again